# Filter response object in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I am making a post request and would like to filter object response to get some data based on condition,so in my object response, I need to filter and find object array for **internet banking**,
based on my finding on google, this is what I tried:

**response object:**

```
{
  "header":
  {
    "serviceId":"xxx",
    "productCode":"xxx",
    "transactionId":"xxx"
  },
  "data":
  {
    "items":
    [
      {
        "paymentModel":"Retail Banking",
        "paymentChannels":
        [
          { "name":"A", "status":"Active" },
          { "name":"B", "status":"Active" },
          { "name":"C", "status":"Active" },
          { "name":"D", "status":"Active" }
        ],
        "name":"Internet Banking",
        "logoUrl":"xxx"
      },
      {
        "paymentModel":"Retail Banking",
        "paymentChannels":
        [
          {
            "bankFeeRate":"0",
            "ccIsRequired":true,
            "name":"R",
            "currency":
            [{
              "isoCode":"xxx",
              "name":"xxx"
            }],
            "bankFeeType":"xxx",
            "paymentChannelId":"9",
            "status":"Active",
            "acceptedCard":
            [
              "visa",
              "mastercard"
            ]
          },
          {
            "bankFeeRate":"0",
            "ccIsRequired":true,
            "name":"M",
            "currency":
            [{
              "isoCode":"xxx",
              "name":"xxx"
            }],
            "bankFeeType":"fixed",
            "paymentChannelId":"13",
            "status":"Active",
            "acceptedCard": [ "amex" ]
          }
        ],
        "name":"Credit Card",
        "logoUrl":"xxx"
      }
    ],
    "metadata": { "count":2 }
  },
  "status":
  {
    "code":"200",
    "message":"OK"
  }
}
```

**component.ts**

```js
getPaymentChannel() {
  this.paymentService.getData(data)
  .pipe( map(
      res => res.filter(items => items.data.items ==='Internet Banking')
      .subscribe(res => console.log(res))
  ))
}
```

I want to display `'PaymentChannels[]'` in html using *ngFor, so I think I need to filter this response by name, which are `credit card` or `internet banking`, this is my stackblitz link [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ghzvle?file=src/app/payment.service.ts),Im new to rxjs and typescript, could someone guide me ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know that you are looking for just one item, you can use `find`, which returns you an object. But let's use `filter` here, since that is what you want to use.

Apparently you want to filter by the `name` inside `items`, therefore your filter should look like:

```ts
 map((res: PaymentModel) => 
   res.data.items.filter((x: Item) => x.name === 'Internet Banking')
```

If found, it will return you an array with all that matches. So now you want to show the `paymentChannels` in the html, iterate the array and add a nested ngFor for iterating `paymentChannels`:

```html
<div *ngFor="let dat of myData">
  <div *ngFor="let p of dat.paymentChannels">
    <!-- ... -->
  </div>
</div>
```

**[Your forked STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hncslw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fpayment%2Fpayment.component.html)**

The same using `find`: **[STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uyxxtu?file=src/app/payment/payment.component.html)**

Comment: thanks, but I had see that people using model to bind with the object response, thats  why in my stackblitz I created model, can you explain about this ?

Comment: I'm sorry, could you rephrase that question. You created a model, what does that mean?

Comment: aah, you mean your classes?

Comment: aah yes..classes, sorry for my bad

Comment: @hafizi I updated both stackblitzes to use your classes!

Comment: thanks a lot ! there are any difference when you classes or not ? and what the best practice ?

Comment: The best practice is definitely to have some type of models. I prefer interfaces over classes if no class-specific methods are needed. But definitely a model, since we are using **Type**Script. It will help you when coding, the compiler can warn you if you are trying to do something that doesn't conform to your model. Have to remember though that interfaces don't exist during runtime, but you make your life so much easier when using models, so keep up with that! :)